# Gives the window leak error when the image is loaded

Tags: android

```
    public class CaptureImage extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "CaptureImage.java";

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> outlets = outlets = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
final static int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

int serverResponseCode = 0;
static String uploadFilePath = " ";
static String Path;
static int delete_image_id = 0;
TextView shift_display;
Uri imageUri = null;
static TextView imageDetails = null;

public static ImageView showImg = null;

CaptureImage CameraActivity = null;
Upload upload;
ProgressDialog dialog_upload = null;

// FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(CaptureImage.this);
static Cursor cursor = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture_image);
    CameraActivity = this;
    showImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showImg);
    upload = new Upload(CaptureImage.this);
    final Button photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    final Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    final Button selet_outlet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.outlet_names);
    photo.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
    upload.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk3);
    selet_outlet.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk4);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        outState.putString("cameraImageUri", imageUri.toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("cameraImageUri")) {
        imageUri = Uri
                .parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));
    }
}

OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("VALUES", "It is Working");
        String fileName = "Camera_Example.jpg";
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Image capture by camera");

        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        /*************************** Camera Intent End ************************/

    }
};

OnClickListener oclBtnOk3 = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (showImg.getDrawable() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this, " Picture was not captured ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            upload_prescription();
        }

    }
};

OnClickListener oclBtnOk4 = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (showImg.getDrawable() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this, " Picture was not captured ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        else {

            // Intent intent = new Intent(CaptureImage.this,
            // Chanel_Display.class);
            // startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

};

public void upload_prescription() {
    dialog_upload = ProgressDialog.show(CaptureImage.this, "",
            "Uploading file...", true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            });

            createDirectoryIfNeeded();
            copy();

            deleteImageFromGallery(delete_image_id + "");
            upload.uploadFile(uploadFilePath);

        }
    }).start();

}

public void deleteImageFromGallery(String captureimageid) {

    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    cursor = null;

    getContentResolver().delete(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] { captureimageid });

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, BaseColumns._ID, };

    Log.i("InfoLog", "on activityresult Uri u " + u.toString());

    try {
        if (u != null) {
            cursor = CaptureImage.this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
                    projection, null, null, null);
        }
        if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.moveToLast())) {

            int i = getContentResolver().delete(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    BaseColumns._ID + "=" + cursor.getString(3), null);
            Log.v(TAG, "Number of column deleted : " + i);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}

public void copy() {

    String sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    uploadFilePath = sdCard + "/Capturetemp/" + getDate() + "_" + "AI"
            + ".jpg";

    File sourceLocation = new File(Path);
    File targetLocation = new File(uploadFilePath);
    Log.v(TAG, "sourceLocation: " + sourceLocation);
    Log.v(TAG, "targetLocation: " + targetLocation);

    try {

        // 1 = move the file, 2 = copy the file
        int actionChoice = 2;

        // moving the file to another directory
        if (actionChoice == 1) {

            if (sourceLocation.renameTo(targetLocation)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Move file successful.");
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Move file failed.");
            }

        }

        // we will copy the file
        else {

            // make sure the target file exists

            if (sourceLocation.exists()) {

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

                // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;

                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copy file successful.");

            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Copy file failed. Source file missing.");
            }

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public String getDate() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate1 = df1.format(c.getTime());

    return formattedDate1;

}

private void createDirectoryIfNeeded() {
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Capturetemp");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        if (direct.mkdir()) {
            // directory is created;
        }

    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start ***************/

            String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri, CameraActivity);

            // Create and excecute AsyncTask to load capture image

            new LoadImagesFromSDCard(CaptureImage.this).execute(""
                    + imageId);

            /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End ****************/

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}

/************ Convert Image Uri path to physical path **************/

public static String convertImageUriToFile(Uri imageUri, Activity activity) {

    int imageID = 0;

    try {

        /*********** Which columns values want to get *******/
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };

        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, proj, null,
                null, null);

        // Get Query Data

        int columnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int file_ColumnIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        // int orientation_ColumnIndex = cursor.
        // getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION);

        int size = cursor.getCount();

        /******* If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card. *****/

        if (size == 0) {

            // imageDetails.setText("No Image");
        } else {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                delete_image_id = imageID;

                Path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);

            }

        }

    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    // Return Captured Image ImageID ( By this ImageID Image will load from
    // sdcard )

    return "" + imageID;
}

public class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    CaptureImage context;

    Bitmap mBitmap;

    public LoadImagesFromSDCard(CaptureImage context) {
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        Dialog.show();

    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bitmap newBitmap = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        try {

            uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""
                            + urls[0]);

            /************** Decode an input stream into a bitmap. *********/
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(uri));

            if (bitmap != null) {

                /********* Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap. ***********/

                newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 350, 350,
                        true);
                // SaveIamge(newBitmap);
                bitmap.recycle();
                if (newBitmap != null) {

                    mBitmap = newBitmap;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error fetching image, try to recover

            /********* Cancel execution of this task. **********/
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        if (mBitmap != null) {
            context.showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (Dialog.isShowing()) {


        }

    }

}
```

}

I tried above code display a image retrieve from SD card it works fine.But when image is loaded on to the screen it returns the following error.Here i used progress dialog to display during the image load.

```
 le.androidchathunservice.CaptureImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@424c0c50 that was originally added here


      02-12 13:15:24.093: E/WindowManager(12019): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidchathunservice.CaptureImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@424c0c50 that was originally added here

        02-12 13:15:24.093: E/WindowManager(12019):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
        02-12 13:15:24.093: E/WindowManager(12019):     at com.example.androidchathunservice.CaptureImage$LoadImagesFromSDCard.onPreExecute(CaptureImage.java:418)
```

Comment: what is **CaptureImage**???

Comment: I upload the Entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change this one...

```
 CaptureImage context;
```

to

```
 Context context;
```

also

```
 public LoadImagesFromSDCard(CaptureImage context) {
    this.context = context;

}
```

to

```
public LoadImagesFromSDCard(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}
```

**EDIT:**

```
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
     super.onPostExecute();

    if (Dialog.isShowing()&& Dialog!=null) {

        Dialog.dismiss();
        Dialog = null;
    }

    if (mBitmap != null) {
        context.showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    }
}
```

Comment: it works first time perfectly.when the second time i captur image and loaded it dosenot work

Comment: context.showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);not works instead of that this work showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

Comment: i use  showImg.setImageBitmap(mBitmap).But still gives the same error

Comment: 02-12 16:03:11.671: E/WindowManager(7703): Activity com.example.androidchathunservice.CaptureImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42309488 that was originally added here
02-12 16:03:11.671: E/WindowManager(7703): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidchathunservice.CaptureImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42309488 that was originally added here

Comment: I think you haven't dismiss your **dialog_upload** dialog

Comment: Ni have closed it correcrly.This error pop up from line 321=new LoadImagesFromSDCard(CaptureImage.this).execute(""
      + imageId); and line 415=Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    Dialog.show(); according to the log cat

Comment: Is your LoadImagesFromSDCard  in one activity? Or different class?

Comment: it is on ImageCapture Activity.(See my code).it sometimes works fine.sometimes not why is that

Comment: Thats means is it only one Activity. ISn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47307/discussion-between-user2771059-and-piyush-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be possible that your CaptureImage activity upon which you created the dialog has already finished by the time you hit onPostExecute(). If that's the case, then attempting the dismiss the dialog would definitely leak the window

Comment: can u eloborate the answer